# What's wrong with my piping code?

Tags: c, shell

I'm trying to create a pipe for a custom C shell that can run something like `cat example.txt | -wc`.

But right now when I run it, I get the shell prompt looping infinitely on the command line.

Can someone tell me what's wrong with how I'm implementing piping, please?

```
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **args){
    pid_t pid,pid2, wpid;
    int pipefd[2];
    int status;
    pipe(pipefd);
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        pid2=fork();
        if(pid2==0)
        {
            dup2(pipefd[0],0);
            close(pipefd[1]);
            if(execvp(args[1],args)==-1)
            {
                perror("Shell Error");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            dup2(pipefd[1],1);
            close(pipefd[0]);
            if(execvp(args[4],args)==-1)
            {
                perror("Shell Error");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Return to Shell
    }
    close(pipefd[0]);
    close(pipefd[1]);

}
```

Comment: For one, you're not handling a *failure* from your `fork()` calls.  Second, I don't see [the creation of any pipes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including test input and output. And please format your code properly with correct indentation.

Comment: `dup2(pipefd[0],0);` What is that supposed to do? `pipefd` is an uninitialized variable and accessing it is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: The original process needs to close its copies of *both* ends of the pipe.

Comment: But I think the larger problem (in your code as presented at this moment) is your `execvp()` calls.  I don't see how it could be correct to pass the main program's argument vector as either child's argument vector.

Comment: hmmm interesting, I'll try some of the suggestions

Comment: I changed it to handle some error handling for if pipe fails like suggested and the original process now closes its copies of both ends of the pipe. So no more infinite error but now when I try to type "cat example.txt | -wc" I get the output "cat: invalid option -- 'w'
Try 'cat --help' for more information.
" I believe this may have to do with the input string needing to be parsed better

Comment: You are not closing all the pipe ends.  The canonical code should look like `dup2(pipefd[0],0); close(pipefd[0]); close(pipefd[1]);`